# How can I get whether a process has executed properly or had some errors while executing?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, process

I have a process that I need to start through WPF using C# as back end. The process is starting properly but in the process there is some error. In other words I can say that the process did not start properly. So how can I get that information on my code-behind?

For Example:

```
p.StartInfo.FileName = BasePath;
p.StartInfo.Arguments = args;
p.Start();
```

But after executing this file I am getting an error that some of the related DLLs are missing.   I know the cause but if I have to detect this error, how could I get it on my code-behind?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Subscribe to the `Process.Exited` event and then check `Process.ExitCode`:

```
public void StartProcess()
{
    p.StartInfo.FileName = BasePath;
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = args;
    p.Start();
    p.Exited += new EventHandler(Process_Exited);
}

void Process_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var p = sender as Process;
    if (p.ExitCode != 0)
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Process failed: ExitCode = {0}", p.ExitCode));
}
```

Comment: Yes Thats correct but there is one more thing it shows me default error by windows the procedure entry point ____ etc. if i want to supress that error aand only show my error box that Process failed how that be possible?

Comment: That is mostly out your control because the error reporting is part of the operating system.  You can try to [disable error reporting](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/7863/disable-error-reporting-in-xp-vista-and-windows-7/).